# CentOS IP gateways

Tags: centos, ip

I have an issue with CentOS 6.3
I currently have 4 IP's on my dedicated server, however they're in pairs, as they're from different subnets - so `46.**.**.**` & `78.**.**.**` - Any IP with the `78.**.**.**` works just fine, as it's using the default route in resolv.confg (under /etc) - however I need to use the two `46.**.**.**` ones for my VPS'. I've tried doing the `Eth0-route` didn't work and I've tried making multiple `Eth0` - `Eth0:1` & so on. Didn't work either - it just gets redirected to the "main" IP. Any help appreciated - thank you.

```
ADDRESS0=0.0.0.0
NETMASK0=0.0.0.0
GATEWAY0=78.46.48.65
ADDRESS1=46.4.141.37
NETMASK1=255.255.255.248
GATEWAY1=46.4.141.33
^ route-eth0
DEVICE=eth0:1
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=46.4.141.37
NETMASK=255.255.255.248
SCOPE="peer 46.4.141.33"
^ Eth0:1 (Eth0 looks similar, just with IPv6 and HWADDR too).
```

Comment: Need this. badly.

Answer (score 1):

If your dedicated host is assigning IP addresses like this, then they should be very familiar with providing support to their customers on how to get it working, so really - ask them, as you may need to use particular IP addresses and gateways on different physical NICs and only they will be able to tell you which these are.

You need to understand what subnet each IP is on, and then a NIC or vNIC that has that IP assigned will need to have a gateway in the same subnet in order to be able to communicate with it.

The config you posted set a gateway in a different subnet to the IP address assigned to the NIC.